# add div class inside php if return

Tags: php, html, css

here is the code i use and i will add a div class for return online and offline  , have try it from examples on this site but get error in script

```
if ($entry['User']['user_id'] > 0)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = sprintf('
            SELECT s.userid
            FROM #__session AS s
            WHERE s.guest = 0 AND s.userid = %d
            LIMIT 1', $entry['User']['user_id']);

    $userid = $db->setQuery($query)->loadResult();

    if ($userid) {
        return "Online";
    }
}  
return "Offline";
```

here is css off div class online and offline ;

```
.online {
position: absolute;
top: -4px;
right: -6px;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #39b54a;
border: 2px solid #fff;
   }

.offline {
position: absolute;
top: -4px;
right: -6px;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #39b54a;
border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

i try this but get error :

```
if ($entry['User']['user_id'] > 0)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = sprintf('
            SELECT s.userid
            FROM #__session AS s
            WHERE s.guest = 0 AND s.userid = %d
            LIMIT 1', $entry['User']['user_id']);

    $userid = $db->setQuery($query)->loadResult();

<div class=online>
if ($userid) {
     return "Online";
}</div>
}
<div class=offline>
return "Offline";
</div>
```

Comment: What error? Plus, your last PHP code is messed up, you are using HTML code inside PHP...

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this mess

```
 <div class=online>
  if ($userid) {
      return "Online";
   }</div>
  }
 <div class=offline>
 return "Offline";</div>
```

Into something like this

```
  if ($userid) {
      return "<div class=online>Online</div>";
   }
  }

 return "<div class=offline>Offline</div>";
```